# Multiple Where in Condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter active record query.

```
function select_in($table,$cond)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where_in('brand_id',$cond);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();  exit;
        return $query;
    }
```

I need to pass another one `where_in` condition in this query.Is it Possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, check an @sgt answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$this->db->where_in('brand_id',$cond);
$this->db->where_in('field' , $cond_new);
```